# Does Keycloak 3.2.1 has WildFly within it

Tags: eclipse, wildfly, keycloak

I am trying to upgrade `Wildfly` and `Keyclock` to their latest releases.
Does `Keyclock` 3.2.1 Final has `Wildfly` integrated into it?

Answer (score 1):

Keycloak Standalone Server is built upon WildFly but it's not meant to deploy other applications on it.